# Big-O Space Complexity of nested operations

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o, space-complexity

If I have nested operations, does this still count as extra-space?

```py
def f(nums1, nums2):
    return len(set(nums1)) < len(set(nums2))
```

Is function `f` considered `O(1)` space complexity as it only creates a boolean value or `O(n+m)` space complexity as the nested `set()` operations create two sets of sizes `n` and `m`?

Comment: Space complexity is how much memory an algorithm uses, not the size of its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n+m), Just Like O(n^2 + n) ~ O(n^2)